# Ruby on Rails にて写真アプリのDelete時のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

前提・実現したいこと

Ruby on Rails にて写真アプリを作成中です。   
写真を「Delete」しようとすると下記のエラーメッセージが表示されてしまいます。 
どのように対処したらよろしいでしょうか？

発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[image: https://gyazo.com/21705ed118a90aaf65dd127e348f4a2f]

ソースコード 1「photos_controller.rb」

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :login_check, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_action :set_current_user_photo, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  # GET /photos.json
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
  end

  # GET /photos/1
  # GET /photos/1.json
  def show
    @photo = Photo.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
    @comments = @photo.comments.includes(:user).all
    @comment = @photo.comments.build(user_id: current_user.id) if current_user
  end

  # GET /photos/new
  def new
    @photo = current_user.photos.build
  end

  # GET /photos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /photos
  # POST /photos.json
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /photos/1
  # DELETE /photos/1.json
  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to photos_url, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def login_check
    unless user_signed_in?
      flash[:alert] = "ログインしてください"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_current_user_photo
    @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :caption, :user_id)
  end
end
```

ソースコード ②「index.html.erb」

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Comments</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Photo</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= comment.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= comment.photo_id %></td>
      <td><%= comment.body %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', comment %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
```

Comment: 写真を削除する画面のコードも載せてもらうとエラーの原因がよりハッキリするかもしれません。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
写真を削除する画面のコードも載せましたので、何卒お願い致します。

Comment: 追加してもらった画面は photos/index.html.erb ではなく、 comments/index.html.erb ではありませんか？この画面のコードだと「コメントを削除」になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

該当データが存在しないようですので、まずはphotosテーブルに削除対象となる該当のデータが存在するか確認してはどうでしょうか？確認の方法は、

- GUIのViewerツール(SequelProなど)で確認する
- `rails consle`コマンドからActiveRecord経由で確認する
- コマンドライン(mysql, psqlなど)で直接確認する

などがあるかと思います。

また、Railsのデバッグで一般的な`pry`を利用するのも一つの手段です。`pry`の導入や使い方に関しては http://ruby-rails.hatenadiary.com/entry/20141024/1414081224 こちらの記事が参考になりますので、よろしければご覧ください。
例えば、今回のコードですと、

```
def set_current_user_photo
  binding.pry
  @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
end
```

上記位置に`binding.pry`を追加し、まずは`current_user.photos`が取得できるかを確認してみて、少しずつ何が原因か探っていくと良いかもしれません。

ちなみに、`find`メソッドは該当データがない場合、今回のように`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`が発生しますので、もし例外を発生させずにエラーハンドリングをしたい場合は`find_by(id: params[:id])`とすると良いかと思います。

参考: 単一のオブジェクトを取り出す
 http://railsguides.jp/active_record_querying.html#%E5%8D%98%E4%B8%80%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99

Comment: ご回答ありがとうござます。
早速内容を確認させて頂きます。
よろしくお願い致します。